# How to do authenticate in Task Module with Message extension

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to develop a message extension which requires a sign in, I'm using an initiate action based ME. In task Module in want to authenticate a user

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Answer (score 0):

Every request to your services includes the obfuscated ID of the user that performed the request, as well as the user's display name and Azure Active Directory object ID.

```
"from": {
  "id": "29:1C7dbRrC_5yzN1RGtZIrcWT0xz88KPGP9sxdpVpV8sODlgPHeQE9RqQ02hnpuKzy6zZ-AaZx6swUOMj_Dsdse3TQ4sIaeebbFBF-VgjJy_nY",
  "name": "Larry Jin",
  "aadObjectId": "cd723fa0-0591-416a-9290-e93ecf3a9b92"
}
```

The id and aadObjectId values are guaranteed to be that of the authenticated Teams user. They can be used as keys to look up credentials or any cached state in your service.

If your service requires user authentication, you need to sign in the user before he or she can use the messaging extension. If you have written a bot or a tab that signs in the user, this section should be familiar.

The sequence is as follows:

1. User issues a query, or the default query is automatically sent to
   your service.
2. Your service checks whether the user has first
   authenticated by inspecting the Teams user ID.
3. If the user has not
   authenticated, send back an auth response with an openUrl suggested
   action including the authentication URL.
4. The Microsoft Teams client launches a pop-up window hosting your webpage using the given authentication URL.
5. After the user signs in, you should close your window and send an "authentication code" to the Teams client.
6. The Teams client then reissues the query to your service, which includes
   the authentication code passed in step 5. Your service should verify
   that the authentication code received in step 6 matches the one from
   step 5.

This ensures that a malicious user does not try to spoof or compromise the sign-in flow. This effectively "closes the loop" to finish the secure authentication sequence.

Here is details link to [Add Authentication to Message Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication).